# delete states when user logout

Tags: flutter, flutter-getx

I am building a simple note-taking app. When the user logs out and logs in again either with the same user or a different user I want to perform a new network call to fetch the notes from the server.
but what happens in my case is the controller saves the state throughout the app life.

Here is my `NoteController` class:

```dart
import 'dart:developer';

import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:get/get.dart';
import 'package:notes_app/models/note_model.dart';
import 'package:notes_app/screens/notes/home_screen.dart';
import 'package:notes_app/services/apis/network_calls.dart';
import 'package:notes_app/services/database_helper.dart';

class NotesController extends GetxController {
  final notesList = <Note>[].obs;
  var titleController = TextEditingController();
  var contentController = TextEditingController();
  RestAPI restAPI = Get.find<RestAPI>();

  @override
  void onInit() {
    super.onInit();
    log("on initialize");
    getAllNotes();
  }

  @override
  void onClose() {
    log("The controller has been deleted");
  }

  bool isNotesListEmpty() {
    if (notesList.value.isEmpty) {
      log("is Empty!");
      return true;
    } else {
      log("is not Empty!");
      return false;
    }
  }

  Future getAllNotes() async {
    var results = await restAPI.fetchAllNotes();
    List<Note> notes = List.generate(
      results.length,
      (index) => Note.fromJson(results[index]),
    );
    log(notes.length.toString());
    notesList.value.addAll(notes);
  }

  @override
  void onInit() {
    super.onInit();
    log("on initialize");
    getAllNotes();
  }

  @override
  void onClose() {
    log("The controller has been deleted");
  }

  bool isNotesListEmpty() {
    if (notesList.value.isEmpty) {
      log("is Empty!");
      return true;
    } else {
      log("is not Empty!");
      return false;
    }
  }

  Future getAllNotes() async {
    var results = await restAPI.fetchAllNotes();
    List<Note> notes = List.generate(
      results.length,
      (index) => Note.fromJson(results[index]),
    );
    log(notes.length.toString());
    notesList.value.addAll(notes);
  }
```

`BindingNotes`:

```dart
import 'dart:developer';

import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:get/get.dart';
import 'package:notes_app/models/note_model.dart';
import 'package:notes_app/screens/notes/home_screen.dart';
import 'package:notes_app/services/apis/network_calls.dart';
import 'package:notes_app/services/database_helper.dart';

class NotesController extends GetxController {
  final notesList = <Note>[].obs;
  var titleController = TextEditingController();
  var contentController = TextEditingController();
  RestAPI restAPI = Get.find<RestAPI>();
```

`DependencyInjection` class:

```dart
import 'package:get/get.dart';
import 'package:notes_app/services/apis/network_calls.dart';

class DependencyInjection {
  static void init() async {
    Get.lazyPut(() => GetConnect());
    Get.lazyPut(() => RestAPI());
  }
}
```